# EditorWindow implementation needs reimport to load asset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i currently try to extend the unity editor with custom EditorWindow implementations. It follows loosely [this guide](http://burgzergarcade.net/scriptableobjects-as-databases-in-unity/).

I try to save a asset containing serialized objects as a sort of database.

That works just fine!

However. If i close unity and reopen it

`db = (FigureDB)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Logic/Database/FigureDB.asset", typeof(FigureDB));`

doesnt load the asset file **unless** i manually reimport the EditorWindow implementation within unity (rightclick on cs-file -> reimport).

I code in Visual Studio (whether this matters or not.... i suspected a line-endings-problem, but it doesnt seem to be the case)

After reopening Unity i also see within the inspector (while selecting the asset) `The associated script can not be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script` (even though there are no compile time errors visible)

Any suggestions? If more info is necessary i will gladly provide them, however it doesnt seem to be a code problem but rather an IDE-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you had use this?

```
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset("Assets/Logic/Database/FigureDB.asset", ImportAssetOptions.Default);
```